# I have 8 single row arrays, how do I combine these into a single array with 8 rows?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a multidimensional array and running into an issue I can't solve. I have 8 single row arrays stored in 8 variables: row1x, row2x, row3x....row8x. Any ideas on how to combine to form one array?

Here's what I have now:

```
var row1x = [325, 654, 47, 696];
var row2x = [567, 274, 685, 84];
var row3x = [252, 111, 2369, 0180];
```

etc

Thanks

Comment: Don't use numbered variable names, but put them in one array right away?

Comment: `empty_arr.push(row1x, row2x, row3x)` or `empty_arr = row1x.concat(row2x, row3x)` ?

Comment: I see 3 answers doing different things that all answer your question.  Can you be more specific about how you want them combined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about simply:

```
var rows = [row1x, row2x, row3x, ... row8x];
```

That will create an array that looks like this:

```
[[325, 654, 47, 696], [567, 274, 685, 84], [252, 111, 2369, 180], ...]
```

Answer (score 2):

This would work.  The last line will alert you with "567".

```
var row1x = [325, 654, 47, 696];
var row2x = [567, 274, 685, 84];
var row3x = [252, 111, 2369, 0180];

var newArray = new Array();
newArray[0] = row1x;
newArray[1] = row2x;
newArray[2] = row3x;

alert(newArray[1][0]);
```

Comment: That's fairly verbose. You can just do `var newArray = [row1x, row2x, row3x]`